# Задача на python - перевернутые предложения

Tags: python, алгоритм

Формат ввода
Строка с текстом. Предложения разделяются точками, на
конце тоже точка.
Формат вывода
Строка с перевёрнутыми предложениями. Порядок
предложений поменяться не должен.

```
Ввод: Я есть Грут. Ты нет.
Вывод: Грут есть я. Нет ты.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: вводится строка Я есть Грут. Ты нет. Выводится Грут есть я. Нет ты.
переворачивание строки не знаю как решить

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?
Помните, что **учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы
пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста,
отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при 
решении задачи (для этого нажмите [edit]). Например, приведите код,
который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2):

Для начала разберитесь, как делить текст на предложения. Используйте, например, `split` для этого с нужным параметром. Дальше точно также можно разделить предложения на отдельные слова с помощью того же `split`. "Перевернуть" полученный список можно разными способами, например, используя функцию `reversed`. Склеить обратно слова и предложения можно с помощью функции `join`. Вам осталось только собрать это всё в единый код, все наводки я вам дал. Но задание вы должны всё-таки выполнить самостоятельно.

Comment: Вот правильные ответы на учебные вопросы:) Только наводки) Правильно!